# Elegant verification of a piece being at the edge of a maze

Tags: algorithm

Let's consider a game where the player has `n` number of pieces on a `x*y` grid. Also the player can move his pieces in any direction (`north`, `south`, `north-east` etc...). Let's assume that the only rule is that the player (when he decides to move) must move a piece for as much as he can.

```
ooooo
.....
.....
.....
.....
```

Player moves the first piece

```
.oooo
.....
.....
.....
o....
```

To make such a function (ignoring for a moment about the other directions that the player can move his piece) we have:

```
while(!AtEdge()){
  move()
}
```

However this `AtEdge` must be configured to check if the piece is at edge depending on the direction of travel. For example:

```
o.....
......
......
```

The first piece is at edge if the direction is `north`, `west` or `north-west` but it's good to go in any other direction.

My thinking at the moment is that I need a switch statement to check if the piece is `AtEdge()` based on the direction of travel. But then I also need a switch statement for the `move` function.

```
switch(direction){
  case NORTH_EAST: //code to move north-east
}
```

This results in 16 `Switch` statements however if the game was 3D and then the number would multiply. Is there a more elegant solution to achieve what I described? Is there a better way to check if the piece can move any further based on direction of travel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position in a `x*y` grid can be represented by coordinates `0 <= px < x` and `0 <= py < y`. (You can also choose `1 <= px <= x` and `1 <= py <= y`, but starting with index/coordinate 0 is more common.)

A single move to a neighbouring field can be represented by a vector `(mx my)` with `mx, my` having each one of the values `-1,0,1`; the combination `(0 0)` is excluded.

Moving now just means adding the move vector to the position giving

```
px_new = px + mx
py_new = py + my
```

Checking if the new position is inside the board can simple be done by:

```
inside = (0 <= px_new) and (px_new < x) and (0 <= py_new) and (py_new < y)
```